# Is there an UserDefined Language of solidity for notepad++ available?

Tags: solidity

Is there an UserDefined Language of solidity for notepad++ available? If so does anyone can share a link?

Comment: I'll try it again :-) Is there an UserDefined Language of solidity for notepad++ available? If so does anyone can share a link?

Answer (score 5):

You can try the Language>J>JavaScript option in notepad++, for checking the formats for solidity. It works for me. Also https://remix.ethereum.org/ is a great way to check the solidity code format and have a virtual run without the hassle of any installation in the terminal.

Comment: thanks! will try the javascript route! I love remix! work with it all the time!

Comment: On Windows, you can skip the mouse clicks by hitting the keyboard sequences ALT-L-J-J-ENTER (caps for readability).

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for one too but couldn't find any, so I made one myself.

Publicly available on [Github](https://github.com/alin1popa/solidity-notepadplusplus-userdefined-highlight). Pull requests welcome :)

Comment: Very good work! Should be promoted on the community somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a dark theme for NotePad++ based on the one above here:

https://github.com/MegaManSE/SolidityDark